# how to return a list of object1 from a join of object1 and object2 and set some properties of object1

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am querying an Entity Framework Code First database which has two separate tables that are joined a primary key (Property1) and foreign key (PropertyX).

I want to return a `<List>MyObject1` but only change one property of `MyObject1` to that of a property of `MyObect2`

Here is my code:

```
 var myQuery = 
    from o1 in _db.MyObject1
    join o2 in _db.MyObject2 on o1.fkProperty10 equals o2.pkPropertyX //join foreign key to primary key
    where o2.PropertyY != null
    select o1;

 var myList = await myQuery.ToListAsync();
```

This returns me a List of `MyObject1`

I then want to set one property of `MyObject1` with the value of a property in `MyObject2`

```
var myQuery = 
    from o1 in _db.MyObject1
    join o2 in _db.MyObject2 on o1.fkProperty10 equals o2.pkPropertyX
    where o2.PropertyY != null
    select new MyObject1Type { 
        Property1 = o1.Property1,
        Property2 = o1.Property2,
        Property3 = o1.Property3
        ...
        Property98= o1.Property98,
        Property99= o2.PropertyZ
    } 
    ;

 var myList = await myQuery.ToListAsync();
```

`MyObject1` has 100 properties so I don't want to set 1 property at a time.

I want to use a shorthand type syntax to say `o1=o1`;
should looks something like:

```
var myQuery = 
    from o1 in _db.MyObject1
    join o2 in _db.MyObject2 on o1.fkProperty10 equals o2.pkPropertyX
    where o2.PropertyY != null
    select new MyObject1Type {
         [this object]=o1, 
         Property99= o2.PropertyZ 
    } 
    ;

 var myList = await myQuery.ToListAsync();
```

If I use

```
select new MyObject1Type {
         this=o1, 
         Property99= o2.PropertyZ 
    }
```

I get the error.

> CS1604    Cannot assign to 'this' because it is read-only ..DNX 4.5.1 cs

How do I fix it the above code to work?

How do I set one property but keep all the other properties the same of `MyObject1`?

Comment: Are you intending to modify the objects in the original list, or create  *new* objects which are effectively clones of the original but with some differences? If you want to modify the original objects, I'd suggest just querying, then use a `foreach` loop to modify them. Side-effects in queries are nasty.

Comment: I am just querying them so don't intend updating the database with the same modified list.

Comment: But you're not just querying them - you're modifying properties. So do you want the query to create new objects or modify the ones that come out of `_db.MyObject1`? Depending on the provider and caching, you *may* get the same (potentially modified) objects out if you then use `from o1 in _db.MyObject1 ...`.

Comment: Correct intead of returning a List<MyObject> I want to return a new object of List<MyObject> and set all its properties to o1 except one property I want to set to o2.Property3

Comment: Right - so first get the list with a *query* (finding things) and then modify it using a `foreach` loop (not querying). (Although you still haven't really explained whether you want to clone each object or modify the one returned by the source...)

Comment: That way I have to store two seperate lists. one of object1 and then another of object2. The I have to iterate through the object 1 list and run a seperate linq query to find its same ID in object 2. Take that property and update object 2 property. I'm using Entity Framework so I'm not modifying the one in the source but creating a new object e.g. a query. THat is not efficient at all. Regarding cloning or modifying, from my understanding this is neither a clone nor an original object but a new object that is created from a query by the database (EF7).

Comment: You don't need to perform multiple queries. You can perform one query which results in a sequence containing the object and all the properties you want to set. You can then iterate over that sequence, perform the modification, and add the object reference to a list. Note that the query sequence doesn't need to be a list - it can just be lazy. My point around clone vs not is still relevant in EF (I believe) due to context caching - if the context "knows" an object reference for a specific row in the database, it may return that for other queries in the same context.

Comment: (It doesn't help that we don't have any idea why you're performing these modifications. What are you planning to do with the objects afterwards? If you're going to save the modifications back to the database, then modifying the objects returned from the query makes a lot of sense. If you just need them in some other context, you might want a different projection instead.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113014/discussion-between-firste-and-jon-skeet).